# mongodb shell login - password contains special characters like # and &

Tags: mongodb, shell, command-prompt, mongodb-shell

I am trying to login to mongodb database using mongodb shell, and if the password contains any special characters like # or & , the authentication fails.

```
mongo mongo.cloud.com:8888/database -u username -p a7IF@WV^#66!

mongo mongo.cloud.com:8888/database -u username -p a7IF@WV^&66!
```

Note: I am using windows command prompt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your password contains special characters like `#`, `&`, `|` and other shell special characters, you need to quote it. Additionally, if your password contains a dollar sign, you need to use single quotes around the password to avoid variable interpolation by your shell.

```
mongo mongo.cloud.com:8888/database -u username -p "a7IF@WV^#66!"
```

or

```
mongo mongo.cloud.com:8888/database -u username -p '${password}a7IF@WV^#66!'
```

Answer (score 0):

What I'm using is next syntax with ***mongosh*** and is working, I'm using it from ***zsh***:

```
~ » mongosh 'mongodb://10.1.3.10:27017,10.1.4.10:27017/?authSource=$external&authMechanism=PLAIN' -u myuser -p '$8#8j9Tc0N'
```

or with a variable like:

```
~ » mypass='$8#8j9Tc0N'
~ » mongosh 'mongodb://10.1.3.10:27017,10.1.4.10:27017/?authSource=$external&authMechanism=PLAIN' -u myuser -p ${mypass}
```